# Using 3rd party library or SDK in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

lets consider I have an Xyz SDK that has special type of activity and delegates, in java you have to do

```
public class MyDemoActivity extends XyzUiActivity implements
   XyzOperationDelegate,
XyzOperationDelegate.OperationListener,
```

.........

```
@Override public void operationEvent(XyzObject t, XyzOperation.XyzObject detailedOperationData) {
```

// code
}

Please any help on how to implement this in nativescript? I'm using typescript and angular.

Comment: Please refer the [docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages#access-android-packages), it covers almost every examples you need.

Comment: Sorry I have read the document. May be I'm missing something? Let's say the name of the package is com.xyz.api and I have a homecomponent like this:  
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit
How can i change that to fullfil this?  
public class HomeActivity extends XyzUiActivity implements XyzOperationDelegate, XyzOperationDelegate.OperationListener  

Thank you again for your help.  

com.xyz.api.XyzUiActivity
com.xyz.api.XyzOperationDelegate
com.xyz.api.XyzOperationDelegate.OperationListener

Comment: I guess you are confused between Angular Component and native Activity. Those will be completely different. With Android, an Activity is the container for every Frame (page-router-outlet) where the Angular component is hosted. So changing the activity has nothing to do with your Angular component. You will probably extend the activity in a separate TS file and adjust webpack `appComponents` configuration to include it.

Comment: I see. Thank you